# Loop outputting above table

Tags: php

In my long journey through the land of php, I have never experienced a problem like this.

I'm trying to throw some data into it's place of a table, but as angry as it is, it'll not let me do my job and decides to crawl on top of it though I've strictly told it to stay below.
So I've come to the conclusion that either my table or the loop is cursed! Which is why I've fought my way to you guys in hope that you'll be able to cure this black sorcery.

My code so far:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Dato</th>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>Hjemme</th>
            <th>Ude</th>
            <th>Mål</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Hejsa</td>
        </tr>
        <?
            $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM kampe ORDER BY dato DESC LIMIT 8");
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<tb>".dateMd("j. F", strtotime($row["dato"]))."</tb>";
                echo "<tb>".date("h:i", strtotime($row["dato"]))."</tb>";
                echo "<tb>hej</tb>";
                echo "<tb>hej</tb>";
                echo "<tb>hej</tb>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Hejsa</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Please at least paste the code in plain text so that we can try to execute it without typing it! Then share with us any troubleshooting you have done so far. Finally, try to find a better title.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about fixing a typo.

Comment: Um......did you read my answer?  Youre wasting your time posting all the code....its a simple fix...

Comment: @KyleK Sorry, was fixing my question the time you wrote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all your `<tb>` with `<td>`, should work then

`<tb>` isn't valid

Comment: Gaargh! GD! Sorry, Now I've been fighting with this for two days and you spot it in less than five minutes D: Thanks! (Whenever I can accept your answer, I'm going to)